# Difficulty in cropping a default size area using jsp

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, jcrop

I'm trying to provide a feature that a user is able to select a part of uploaded image which fits exactly to my "div" for the image. I've almost done the required thing using the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Cropper</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.Jcrop.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script language="Javascript">

$(window).load(function() {
var jcrop_api;
var i, ac;

initJcrop();

function initJcrop() {
        jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#target', {
        onSelect: storeCoords,
        onChange: storeCoords,
    setSelect:   [50, 0, 1000,330],
    allowResize: false      
        });




};
function storeCoords(c) {
jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
jQuery('#H').val(c.h);
};        
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="<%=path%>" id="target" />
<form name="myForm" action="cropper.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id = "X" name="X" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" id = "Y" name="Y" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" id = "W" name="W" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" id = "H" name="H" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Crop Image"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the only problem I'm facing is that the default crop area disappears if the user clicks anywhere outside the crop area which is not what I want.

What can be the option to keep the default crop space intact even if user clicks outside it?

Comment: Aside from using `<%=path%>` to print out a variable (which wasn't even declared), this has nothing to do with jsp at all.

Comment: @developerwjk I've just shown the code for cropping the image. As I said the main problem I'm facing is regarding the default crop space therefore I only uploaded the code regarding the cropping of image. If you want I can upload the JSP code also.